# How to understand the output data when foldLeft is applied on a dataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to remove new line characters from a Dataframe's String columns using foldLeft & regex_replace in Scala. The dataframe is created after reading an RDBMS table: public.test_sid on postgres. The table has 4 columns: `id, id1, id2, id3` and `id3` has a new line character in it.
This is how I have written the logic:

```
var conf  = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark-JDBC").set("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval","120s").set("spark.network.timeout","12000s").set("spark.default.parallelism", "20")
val conFile       = "testconnection.properties"
val properties    = new Properties()
properties.load(new FileInputStream(conFile))
val connectionUrl = properties.getProperty("gpDevUrl")
val devUserName   = properties.getProperty("devUserName")
val devPassword   = properties.getProperty("devPassword")
val driverClass   = properties.getProperty("gpDriverClass")
try {
  Class.forName(driverClass).newInstance()
} catch {
  case cnf: ClassNotFoundException =>
    System.exit(1)
  case e: Exception =>
    System.exit(1)
}
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).master("yarn").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  val spColsDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url",connectionUrl).option("dbtable", "(select * from public.test_sid) as sampleTab").option("user", devUserName).option("password", devPassword).load()
  val strCols = spColsDF.schema.fields.filter(_.dataType==StringType).map(_.name)
  val finalDF = strCols.foldLeft(spColsDF){ (tempdf, colName) => tempdf.withColumn(colName, regexp_replace(col(colName), "\\n", " ")) }
  println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
  spColsDF.show()
  println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
  finalDF.show()
  println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
}
```

In the output log,
From dataFrame: `spColsDF`, I see the data in the format it was inserted.

```
+--------------------+--------------------+----+---+
|                  id|                 id1| id2|id3|
+--------------------+--------------------+----+---+
|1.000000000000000000|1.000000000000000000|   a|
a|
+--------------------+--------------------+----+---+
```

But the data in `finalDF` comes out in a weird format. The value from last column: id3 is found at the beginning of the dataframe and the first digit of the first column: id gets truncated and presented as '000000000000000000' instead of '1.000000000000000000'.

```
+--------------------+--------------------+----+---+
|                  id|                 id1| id2|id3|
+--------------------+--------------------+----+---+
 a|000000000000000000|1.000000000000000000|   a|
+--------------------+--------------------+----+---+
```

The data of the column: `id3` comes first

If I just access that particular column: id3 from finalDF, I get the data as below:

```
scala> finalDF.select(finalDF("id3")).show
+---+
|id3|
+---+
 a|
+---+

scala> finalDF.select(finalDF("id")).show
+--------------------+
|                  id|
+--------------------+
|1.000000000000000000|
+--------------------+
```

Is it just a console issue while printing the data or is there a flaw in the code ?
Could anyone let me know if there is anything wrong in the code I have written above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a CRLF (a.k.a. \r\n) issue.

Historically, one is used to tell the console to go back at the beginning of the line, and the other one to create a new line.

Here, it seems that you suppressed the creation of the new line, but still have the "go back to the beginning" part.

So I suggest you replace **both** `\r` and `\n`.

See [Wikipedia on CR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)

> A carriage return, sometimes known as a cartridge return and often shortened to CR,  or return, is a control character or mechanism used to reset a device's position to the beginning of a line of text. It is closely associated with the line feed and newline concepts, although it can be considered separately in its own right.

To see it in action, let's create a test dataframe :

```
scala> val dataframe = Seq(
     ("normal", "normal"), 
     ("withLF", "normal\n"), 
     ("withCRLF", "normal\r\n")).toDF("id", "value")
dataframe: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, value: string]

scala> dataframe.show
+--------+--------+
|      id|   value|
+--------+--------+
|  normal|  normal|
|  withLF| normal
|
|withCRLF|normal
|
+--------+--------+
```

Here, we see that our strings with "\r\n" and "\n" have the issue you observe at the start of your post.
Now, if I use you replace function :

```
dataframe.withColumn("value", regexp_replace($"value", "\n", "")).show
+--------+-------+
|      id|  value|
+--------+-------+
|  normal| normal|
|  withLF| normal|
|withCRLF|normal
+--------+-------+
```

We see we have solved the "\n" situation, but not the "\r\n". So if you really want to use a regex for your search / replace, you should declare both CR and LF to be replaced :

```
scala> dataframe.withColumn("value", regexp_replace($"value", "[\r\n]+", " ")).show
+--------+-------+
|      id|  value|
+--------+-------+
|  normal| normal|
|  withLF|normal |
|withCRLF|normal |
+--------+-------+
```

(Possible enhancements : de not use a regexp for a single char replacement. Do not output a blank char at the end of the output string, ...).

Comment: Could you tell me parameter should I replace the "\\n" with ? This is in posgtress DB and my colleague told me I have to use "\\n" instead of "\n" for new line character.

Comment: @NewComer I've edited to clarify. Please note that this has *nothing* to do with Spark or Postgre. You could drop all this and work in pure Scala, just using Strings, and have the same behavior.
But for the sake of placing things into your context, I've kept the Spark part.

Comment: I am not using it for a single character replacement. I have multiple cases where in I have to use a nested regex_replace. But it took me so long to find that "foldLeft" is helpful in this case.